# Using UNIX how to merge 3 files into a single file, i.e (Header file, Detailed file, and Trailer file)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have 3 files (Header file, Detailed file, and Trailer file). For example..

Header file contains data like below
H.txt

```
H Chris 3434
```

Detail file contains data like below
D.txt

```
D History 2 02/20/2018   
D Maths   2 02/20/2018  
D Science 2 02/20/2018  
D Biology 2 02/20/2018
```

Trailer record like below
T.txt

```
T 02/20/2019
```

I want a final file with below data..

```
H Chris 3434  
D History 2 02/20/2018  
D Maths   2 02/20/2018  
D Science 2 02/20/2018  
D Biology 2 02/20/2018  
T 4 02/20/2019
```

Comment: `cat H.txt D.txt T.txt` ??

Comment: Already tried cat H.txt D.txt T.txt > result_file and also cat H.txt D.txt T.txt >> result_file.. Both results in single line.

Comment: So there must be a single line only in three the files. `cat` is a really simple utility. It outputs the files. Point. Check the content in the files. `Both results in single line.` - what is the content of that line?

Comment: H Chris 3434  D History 2 02/20/2018  D Maths   2 02/20/2018  D Science 2 2/20/2018  D Biology 2 02/20/2018  T 4 02/20/2019

Comment: So: you get one long line with the content of the files? Maybe the files use windows line endings or some other strange line endings. Try using `dos2unix` utility. Try inspecting the output of `hexdump -C` on the files.

Comment: After converting the input files into unix using the following command ( tr -d '\15\32') doesn't work..

Comment: You need to know what to search for. Are you sure there are newlines in the files as they are now? Can you post the output of `hexdump -C` of the files?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > result_file
```

OR

```
for f in file1 file2 file3 ; do while read line; do echo -e "$line" >> result_file ; done < $f; done
```

Comment: Already tried cat H.txt D.txt T.txt > result_file and also cat H.txt D.txt T.txt >> result_file.. Both results in single line..

Comment: @John  you would obviously need to replace `file1 file2 file3` with your actual file names...

Comment: Yes i replaced with my file names

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your files. Both of my suggestions work fine for me